# Creating a new frame without creating new window

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In my app I have four buttons, which on click invoke particular functions,

```
void optionFrame::searchUserClick(wxCommandEvent& event){
  searchFrame* searchUser = new searchFrame(this);
  searchUser->Show();
}
```

I am calling the constructor and showing it with its member function, The problem here is a new frame is created but a new window is created too.

Any way I can prevent opening new window?

**EDIT 1:**
The structure of myapp is as follow:
I have a toplevel frame which opens when the app starts, I have some buttons in that frame which when clicked takes the user to new frame, But when I see on my taskbar I can see 2 different windows opened and can toggle between those.

But I dont want my user to toggle in between those frame, I want the user to  be able to see only one frame at a time

Comment: As far as I know, a frame should be a top class for a window. You should use `wxPanel` to draw different content in a frame. There is also `wxNotebook` that stores frames as tabs in a single window.

Comment: @IcanCode, its not clear what you mean by opening a window with xFrame? WxFrme is a top level window as already mentioned. If you really want that take a look at MDI architecture. Otherwise you should crete wxDialog/wxFrame.

Comment: "the problem here is a new frame is created but a new window is created too." does not make any sense...

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/classwx_task_bar_button.html